# How to close browser pop-ups using Selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to automate a download using Python and Selenium. In the start page, a pop-up appears on the page:

[image]

How  can I close it using Selenium?

I tried the following ways but all failed:

```
>>> alert = browser.switch_to_alert()

>>> alert.accept()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/alert.py", line 80, in accept
    self.driver.execute(Command.ACCEPT_ALERT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoAlertPresentException: Message: no alert open
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 4.4.0-57-generic x86_64)

>>> alert.dismiss()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/alert.py", line 71, in dismiss
    self.driver.execute(Command.DISMISS_ALERT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoAlertPresentException: Message: no alert open
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 4.4.0-57-generic x86_64)


>>>alert = browser.switch_to_window('Open xdg-open?')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 531, in switch_to_window
    self._switch_to.window(window_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/switch_to.py", line 92, in window
    self._driver.execute(Command.SWITCH_TO_WINDOW, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 4.4.0-57-generic x86_64)


>>> alert = browser.switch_to.window("Open xdg-open?")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/switch_to.py", line 92, in window
    self._driver.execute(Command.SWITCH_TO_WINDOW, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 4.4.0-57-generic x86_64)
```

Comment: How about switching to the dialog box and click on 'Don't open' :
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"ui-dialog") and @aria-describedby="dialogContent2"]//button[@title="Dont't open"]').click()

Comment: have you tried using explicit waits for the alert to be present ?

Comment: @RayhaneMama What is explicit waits? How I can do it?

Comment: @anshulGupta doesn't work. Can't fine this element in the page.

Comment: @Abraham you might have to modify the elements like div contains etc, based on your DOM. I have given you an example.

Comment: @Abraham I am having same problem .  Have you managed to get solution ?

Comment: @anshulGupta This kind of dialog is not part of the DOM but browser native. Anotherpossible way to solve this problem ist to send the `escape` key. I did not encounter the issue in Python but in Elixir.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you face is, that the popup is not part of the DOM and thus can neither be handled by selenium by sending keystrokes nor waiting nor clicking somewhere. The popup is a browser native popup and thus can only be handled by the browser itself, usually by user interaction.

To prevent the interaction you can define beforehand which action the browser should take in the circumstance that a link uses a certain protocol. Think hrefs with telephone links:

```
<p>Book now, call <a href="tel:01234567890">01234 567 890</a></p>
```

The user preferences have to be changed on/before browser start. The handling of protocol schemes can be predefined in the user preferences. In my case I wanted to deny handling of the scheme `tel://`.

To change the user preferences on startup extend the browsers capabilities and specify user preferences under `prefs` of the `chromeOptions`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option( "prefs", {'protocol_handler.excluded_schemes.tel': false})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

In your case it is probably a googlePlay link. So instead of `tel: false` use the protocol in question instead of `tel`.

Answer (score -1):

You should first try this in order to see if it's an error related to waits.
i.e : if your browser doesn't have enough time to find the alert dialog before making actions. You can learn more about explicit waits. [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

you will also need [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html) package and try the following:

```
# add these imports
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

#try to find the alert and do stuff
try:
    #wait for the alert to show up
    WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present(),
                               'Timed out waiting for PA creation ' +
                               'confirmation popup to appear.')
    #if it does
    alert = browser.switch_to.alert()
    alert.accept()
    print "alert accepted"
except TimeoutException:
    print "no alert"
```

Note that i precised to wait for 3 seconds, you can change it to whatever you like.

if this solution doesn't work, you should try a trick to explicitly select the dialog popup by name or text etc..

Comment: Not working and we cannot find dailog popup by name as its not part of source code of currently open page

Comment: It's not part of the DOM but Browser native. How to close that?