# Dismiss dialog selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I am working on a Selenium script, wherein I am trying to dismiss following dialog

[image]

Unfortunately, the following options do not work

```
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
//OR setting following options
options.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.DISMISS);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to send key Enter or send Tab and then Enter. It depends which is the active button.
[sendKeys() in Selenium web driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268617/sendkeys-in-selenium-web-driver)

I also have seen alerts that cannot be handled with Selenium. [Here](https://www.eviltester.com/webdriver/faqs/why-does-selenium-not-work-with-this-alert/) is some more info on why this could happen.

Comment: The suggested options doesn't work. As the dialog mentioned in the problem is not typical javascript alert. This has something to do with protocol_handler configuration. Do you have any idea how to set it in Java? Here is an answer that says it works with Python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44880283/how-to-close-browser-pop-ups-using-selenium-in-python